# Decomposing posets into countably many chains

Tags: set-theory, co.combinatorics, posets, order-theory

A conjecture of Galvin's is that the following is possible (which I take to mean that the consistency of the following can be proven relative to the consistency of something like ZFC, or ZFC plus some large cardinal):

> A partially ordered set $P$ can be decomposed into countably many chains iff the same is true of every suborder $P_0 \subseteq P$ of size at most $\aleph _1$.

You can see it stated as Conjecture 3.3 in [Todorcevic's "Combinatorial Dichotomies in Set Theory"](http://www.math.toronto.edu/~stevo/dichotomies4.pdf).

I'm interested in this conjecture and determining its consistency strength, but in order to get a feel for it I want to first look at it in a special case in which it's supposed to be (according to Todorcevic, if I understood what he told me correctly) provable from ZFC alone.  I'll actually list three special cases of increasing generality; an answer to the last case would be ideal but I'd be happy to see an answer for the first case.

1. Galvin's conjecture, restricted to posets $P$ which are the Cartesian product of two linear orders (with the obvious product ordering).
2. GC restricted to posets which are the Cartesian product of countably many linear orders (countable = finite or denumerable).
3. GC restricted to posets which are subsets of some Cartesian product of countably many linear orders.

Comment: Amit, do you have any references or know where the conjecture was posed?

Comment: Yup, one of Todorcevic's papers, I've included a link above now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've investigated Galvin's Conjecture quite a bit over the past few years. Here is a [preprint](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~dorais/docs/galvin.pdf) of mine on the subject. In there, I show that Galvin's Conjecture restricted to finite-dimensional posets (posets which are subsets of some cartesian product of finitely many linear orderings) is equivalent to Rado's Conjecture (which was extensively studied by Todorcevic). Unfortunately, the ℵ<sub>0</sub>-dimensonal case has eluded me; perhaps you will have better luck...

Comment: Thanks!  You mention in your paper that GC for finite dimensional posets is equivalent to RC, and that a supercompact cardinal gives an upper bound on the consistency strength of RC.  Do you know of a lower bound?  I think Todorcevic mentioned that RC implies the failure of square everywhere, but what about a lower bound in terms of large cardinals? (related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53467/what-is-the-consistency-strength-of-the-failure-of-square-in-terms-of-large-card)

Comment: I haven't looked at RC lower bounds for a while. Since RC implies CC, one lower bound is that of an $\omega_1$-Erdos cardinal, but this is surely very crude.